# Customizing menu link output

Tags: 7, routes, theming

In Drupal 7, how I can intercept menu rendering in template.php and add pipes after menu links?

I tried using template_preprocess_menu_tree but I don't think that is what I am looking for. I want to change the HTML structure of a couple of menus.

Comment: Are you talking of any menu link, or just to the menu local task links?

Comment: Custom menus, Main Menu, not local tasks.

Comment: My comment from _Sep 27 '13_ Using HTML in a menu option would be very useful from a module too, i.e. inserting an image as a menu option. Is there a way to do use something like `function MODULE_preprocess_menu_link(&$variables)`.

PS: I'll ask this as a separate question too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[theme_menu_link()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7) did the trick. It contains an array under element of `#original_link` which has the menu name in it. Using that, I can add pipe delimited links to certain menus.

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7

Answer (score 5):

This may be helpful. You can use preprocess functions to change or add something to menu link.

```php
function THEME_preprocess_menu_link(&$variables) {
  $variables['element']['#below']['#markup'] = ' <span>→</span>';
}
```

In this code span added to every navigation link item.

Answer (score 5):

Personally I'd just add the pipe with CSS - you don't really want the pipes in your markup as they're purely presentational:

```
.breadcrumb li:after {
  content: "|";
  margin: 0 5px; // optional styling nicety
}

.breadcrumb li:last-child::after {
  content: "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Menus are themed with the theme_links function. You'll want to create a copy in your [themes folder]/MYTHEME/template.php and rename it to MYTHEME_links. You can find the default function for drupal 7 by visiting: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme_links/7

Now you'll be able to customize how the menus look from the template.php file.

Comment: This isn't working either. It only dumps the contextual links (using krumo and var_dump on $variables). This is what I used in D6 pretty sure, but doesn't seem to touch menus in a menu block.

Comment: I needed to only do this to certain menus, this answer helped. theme_menu_link contains an array about the menu it is in, so I could then adjust the output if it was a particular menu. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317462/drupal-override-custom-menu-template/6495105#6495105

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use a plugin for this. Full tutorial here: [Create a menu link with html markup in drupal 8](https://stefvanlooveren.me/blog/create-menu-link-html-markup-drupal-8)

```
namespace Drupal\MYMODULE\Plugin\Menu;

use Drupal\Core\Menu\MenuLinkDefault;

/**
 * A menu link that displays number of points.
 */
class MyMessagesMenuLink extends MenuLinkDefault {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getTitle() {
    $count = 0;
    if(\Drupal::currentUser()->isAuthenticated()) {
      // Load in your count here
      ...
    }
    return $this->t('My messages <span class="badge badge-dark">@count</span>', ['@count' => $count]);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getCacheMaxAge() {
    return 0;
  }

}
```