# Automatically group the sub menu items in drupal 7

Tags: routes

My website contains project for following categories-

1. C language
2. Java language
3. Shell script

I have a custom content type "project", which has these fields as radio button. I have a menu item in main menu called project, which has above three categories as sub menu item. I want whenever I add any "C language" project, it should automatically attach as a sub menu item of "C language".

How to achieve it?

Comment: Automatically adding items to menu could be done in hook_entity_presave with menu_link_save function. In that case you just need to update the links in case category changes. Is there any reason you not to just inject them from views in theme functions (http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9154/customizing-menu-link-output)?

Comment: @user20301: Can you please explain me little more? Also I didn't get that what do you mean by "just inject them from views in theme functions". Is there any other way to achieve my requirement?

Answer (score 1):

You could make links list attachment with views for each taxonomy term and then add them in theme_menu_link function if the link in variables matches. Note that requires customization in template.php