# how to alter a hook_field_insert

Tags: hooks, entities

I am trying to find a way of altering the output of a hook_field_insert. In my exact example, I'm trying to hook into the link_field_insert hook, in the Link module:

```
/**
* Implements hook_field_insert().
*/
function link_field_insert($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, &$items) {
  foreach ($items as $delta => $value) {
    _link_process($items[$delta], $delta, $field, $entity);
  } 
}
```

and make a modification to the _link_process function, without actually having to hack the Link module. Is thi possible?

Just to have some background, what my end goal is to add a new form field on the node page for the user to enter link classes, and these classes would be autmatically applied to the link. I have already overridden the theme_link_field to add this form field and its value shows up in the $items array in the above function, so I just need to know how to override the above function.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to alter the hook. You can implement the hook. But in your case maybe you want to use theme_menu_link() instead
[Customizing menu link output](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9154/customizing-menu-link-output)

also check https://api.drupal.org/comment/55298#comment-55298

Comment: This isn't a menu link, this is a link field. And implementing the hook doesn't seem to work, as it says in the docs: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_update/7 - this hook works on a field defined by the module.