# show amount of results for exposed filter

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have a couple of exposed filters to filter the content in my view.
Most of them are taxonomy terms, now i would like to show how many nodes are tagged with that term behind the taxonomy term.

example:

```
London (5)
Paris (3)
Madrid (2)
...
```

Any idea how i can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i created a module with a `hook_form_alter()`.

In that function i created a query that counted the nodes attached to a certain taxonomy term and added this number at the end of every term.

Comment: Any chance to see the code you've used for this? THX in advance!

Comment: @Volker: I've just added an answer with some sample code...

Answer (score 4):

Here is some sample code to do this:

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    switch($form_id) {
        case 'views_exposed_form':

            $allowed_categories = db_query("SELECT 1 as tid, "Term Name (2)" as `name`")->fetchAllKeyed();
            $allowed_categories = array_reverse($allowed_categories, TRUE);
            $allowed_categories['All'] = '- Any -';
            $allowed_categories = array_reverse($allowed_categories, TRUE);

            $form['field_category_tid']['#options'] = $allowed_categories;

            break;
    }
}
```

Just change the query to return 2 columns - the tid and the name with a count.

Answer (score 1):

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch($form_id){
    case 'views_exposed_form':
      if ($form_state['view']->name == 'viewname') {
    //must add some bool so this doesn't get into infinite loop
    if(!isset($form_state['view']->gg)){
      $form_state['view']->gg = TRUE;
      $form_state['view']->execute();
    }

    $form['results_count'] = array(
      '#markup' => t('!count results match your criteria', array('!count' => '<b>'.$form_state['view']->total_rows.'</b>')),
      '#weight' => -99,
    );
      }

      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. While this code might answer the question, it would be in a good tone to explain *why* and *how* it is supposed to work, so the OP could learn from it, not only rely on others to write pieces for him. It looks like ideas and knowledge are what he is after, and that's a good thing that should be encouraged :)

Comment: the loop thing was a very useful advice ! thks

Answer (score 0):

Couple of links (may be useful)

1. Module [Taxonomy Menu](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu), that has count option.
2. [Question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9121/how-can-i-display-a-views-count-in-a-navigation-item/9211#9211) about these things, but without trusted answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example from my real site. field_marka_prochnosti is a field of a node represented by a taxonomy vocabulary. I used phpMyAdmin to learn the name of a table and the name of the field of that table to make a query. bricksale_omega is the name of my theme.

```
function bricksale_omega_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
switch($form_id){
case 'views_exposed_form':

  foreach ($form['field_marka_prochnosti_tid']['#options'] as $tid => &$value) {
    $query = db_select('field_data_field_marka_prochnosti', 'f')
            ->condition('f.field_marka_prochnosti_tid', $tid);
    $query->addExpression('COUNT(*)');
    $count = $query->execute()->fetchField();
    $value = $value . ' (' . $count . ')';
  }

  break;
  }
}
```