# Show total amount of results for an exposed filter

Tags: views, search

Found this answer, [show amount of results for exposed filter](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9365/show-amount-of-results-for-exposed-filter) and this answer.

However, my issue is that i'm trying find the total number of results after executing an exposed filter.

[Views calc](https://drupal.org/project/views_calc) looks like it only returns the count of results from a single result not an exposed filter result. Or if i'm wrong please correct me.

Anyways, the question: How do you find the total number of results from an exposed filter?

**Desired result:**

- Complete an exposed result form
- return "x number of results found" as a block

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm using Views 3.7 in Drupal 7 right now and finally found out you simply can add a result summary `Global: Result summary` to the header/footer.

Answer (score -1):

By using the below code, you can do that, It will display like this ***Showing 1-10 of 130 results***. on your result page.

Put this code in the **Header and set the input filter as PHP code** in your view.

> ```
> <?php
> global $pager_page_array, $pager_total_items, $pager_total;
> $my_view = views_get_current_view();
> $items_per_page = $my_view->pager['items_per_page'];
> if ($pager_total[0] == 1) {
>   echo t('Showing <b>!pager_total_items</b> results',
>     array('!pager_total_items' => $pager_total_items[0])
>   );
> } else {
>   $start = 1 + ($pager_page_array[0] * $items_per_page);
>   $end = (1 + $pager_page_array[0]) * $items_per_page;
>   if ($end > $pager_total_items[0]) $end = $pager_total_items[0];
>   echo t('Showing !start-!end of <b>!pager_total_items</b> results',
>     array('!start' => $start, '!end' => $end, '!pager_total_items' => $pager_total_items[0])
>   );
> }
> ?>
> ```

Comment: Could i just create a custom module and place it in there somehow?

Comment: Why do you want to create custom module, just put this code in header of the view. It will display in the result page.

Comment: I want to avoid using php filter; as it's a security issue.