# Views exposed filter

Tags: views, 7, search

I want to display the node count along with the filter in views exposed filter same feature like facets can any one help me out in this.

Comment: You may want to refer to the issue in this link
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9365/show-amount-of-results-for-exposed-filter