# How to add results count in exposed filter?

Tags: 7, views

I have a view with some better exposed filter and I'd like to add the count of items for each filter like this (but without using facets) :

```
Term 1 (7) - Term 2 (5) - Term 3 (8) ...
```

I saw this [solution](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9365/show-amount-of-results-for-exposed-filter) but, I'd prefer using the query directly from my view or better using the view itself.

The problem is that inside a `hook_form_alter()`, every function related to this view (like `views_get_view_result()`) crashes Apache.

```
function mymodule_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-my-view-page') {
    $v = views_get_view_result('my_view', 'page');
    dpm($v);
  }
}
```

Any better idea for accomplishing this ?

Comment: Please visit:
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9365/show-amount-of-results-for-exposed-filter

Comment: If you read my question you can see that I  mentioned it, but it wasn't a good fit for me.