# Execute a view without rendering

Tags: 7, views

I'd like to programmatically execute a view (providing arguments) and get the raw results, without rendering it. Is it possible?

When I use `$view->preview('default', $args);` it converts the results to HTML. I know I can use `$view->result` to iterate the raw results, but the custom rendered I'm using for some fields are buggy and give me a WSOD (I have no interest or ability to fix the renderer, it's an edge case :) )

I'm using Views 3 with Drupal 7

Comment: Maybe $view->execute() can help.
Simple example: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9121/how-can-i-display-a-views-count-in-a-navigation-item/9211#9211

Answer (score 11):

There is already a function that does exactly what you want:

```
  $result = views_get_view_result('my_view_name', 'default', $arg1, $arg2, ...);
```

Read more at its page at api.drupal.org:

https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_get_view_result/7

Answer (score 4):

$view->preview() is generally used to simply view the display so in other words it will render it via the specified format.

$view->execute_display() also returns the display in relevant format specified in view.

I think you may have to result to executing query direct i.e. db_query()

Comment: I guess I'll just have to resort to building the query myself with db_query. Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 2):

You should get some success if you stub out `view::preview()` into your own code, but change it so that, instead of calling `->display_handler->preview()`, it calls `->execute()` instead:

```
$view = views_get_view($view_name);
$view->set_display($display_name);
$view->preview = TRUE;
$view->pre_execute($args);
$view->execute($display_name);
```

This should work because, for most display handlers, the call to `...->display_handler->preview()` is actually just a wrapper around a call back to `view::render()`. Which itself starts by calling `$this->execute(...)`.